# What spotless must depend on?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradle-plugin, spotless

I added `diffplug/spotless` plugin to my project placing it as a dependency of a `build` task.

```
tasks.build.dependsOn(tasks.integrationTest, tasks.spotlessJava
```

I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':spotlessJava' (type 'SpotlessTaskImpl').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\my-project'.

    Reason: Task ':spotlessJava' uses this output of task ':compileTestJava' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depe
nding on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':compileTestJava' as an input of ':spotlessJava'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':compileTestJava' from ':spotlessJava' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':compileTestJava' from ':spotlessJava' using Task#mustRunAfter.
```

So I started adding dependencies which was displayed in the error.
The code passes `gradlew clean build` only after adding this horrible list:

```
tasks.spotlessJava.dependsOn(tasks.quarkusGenerateCodeDev, tasks.quarkusGenerateCodeTests, tasks.processTestResources, tasks.quarkusBuild, tasks.integrationTest, tasks.prepareDeployment)
```

Is that really necessary? Why `spotlessJava` has to depend on `integrationTest`?
I would prefer to run spotless before integration tests.

Comment: This thread https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-7-0-seems-to-take-an-overzealous-approach-to-inter-task-dependencies/39656 is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had `include '**/*.java'` and now I added `exclude '**/build/generated/**'` to prevent spotless looking into generated code. Now the spotless task does not use the ouptput of eg. `quarkusGenerateCodeDev`. So the answer of @Simon Jacobs helped to some extent.